# How to remove + sign from customizable option from front view in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using Magento2. Now I want to remove the plus sign from the Customizable Options in the product section.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First copy below file from /vendor to your /custom theme.

/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

Copy to
    /your_theme/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

//change line no 38 and use the below code. 
echo str_replace('+','',$block->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false))

Comment: I copied file from vendor folder, Now where to put this file. I am not getting your point /custom theme folder because there is no folder in root directory

Comment: Find the below example link : app/design/frontend/Testnamespace/yourthemename/Magento_Bundle/templates/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml

Comment: There is no such folder name 'Magento_Bundle' in my theme folder. Should I create same path like you mentioned ?

Comment: You have to create this path in your theme.